# Craft 2.4.2669 and SVG's?

Tags: assets

have update craft and when uploading an SVG to Assets nothing happens? The upload bar pops up but the file is not uploaded and is not on the server?

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Does uploading other file types work? Did SVG upload work before you updated to 2669? Have you turned on [dev mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode)? Are you seeing any related error messages in your log (```/craft/storage/runtime/logs```)?

Comment: I have voted to close this as it's a bug report/support request.

Comment: Lee, please get in touch with Pixel & Tonic support and they will assist you: support@pixelandtonic.com

Answer (score 1):

Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for the underlying error message, but most likely you're using [GD](https://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) instead of [Imagick](https://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), which is required for SVG thumbnails/transforms to work properly.

Comment: Let's say you have Imagick and the control panel confirms it's installed. The only thing _not_ present is iconv. Is that required too, or should one submit a bug report? (No mention of `csv` anywhere in the logs.)

Comment: `iconv` is not related. Submit a ticket from your dashboard's Get Help widget.